# What might cause a Speedlight 380EX to stop syncing correctly?

Tags: canon, flash

I have a Canon Speedlight 380EX and some time ago it stopped syncing correctly. Every photo I take comes out dark as if the flash didn't fire.
The flash fires, the IR assist beam works as intended and the E-TTL indicator is on. Tried with two cameras (40D and 70D) with same results.

Is it misconfiguration issue, or malfunction in the flash?

Answer (score 1):

That is an older flash. originally designed for EOS film cameras. Although it has E-TTL, it is probably not worth repairing since you can replace it pretty cheaply.

http://www.usa.canon.com/app/pdf/support/380EX20110907.pdf

You can test it by setting the camera to M with a long shutter speed like 1 second. Keep increasing the speed to see if it fails and where.

Comment: Older but works just fine with modern EOS cameras.

Answer (score -3):

Your shutter speed must not be higher than 1/125s or it won't be able to see the flash light.

Comment: The flash sync speed isn't 1/125s for those cameras...